# getting token value in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I have the following Json which I wish to loop through in vb.net and extract
Given and Family from director

```
 "director": {
    "lineage": null,
    "given": "Na",
    "honourific": null,
    "family": "Jes"
  },
  "creators": [
    {
      "name": {
        "lineage": null,
        "given": "Ju",
        "honourific": null,
        "family": "Pa"
      },
      "id": "ju-anne.n@etu.un-.fr"
    }
  ],
```

voici mon code :

```
    For k = 0 To imax
                    creators = jsonData(k)("creators")

                    director = jsonData(k)("director")

                    'Dim c As New Object

                    Dim result2 As String = Replace(director.ToString, "{[", "")
                    result2 = Replace(result2.ToString, "]}", "")


                    Dim n As JObject = JObject.Parse(result2)
                    Dim result As List(Of JToken) = n.Children().ToList

                    For Each item As JProperty In result
                        item.CreateReader()

                        Select Case item.Name
                            Case "given"

                                'strgiven = item.Value.ToString
                                Dim strgiven As String

                                For Each subitem As JObject In item.Values
                                    strgiven = subitem("given")

                                Next

                            Case "family"

                                Dim strfamily As String

                                For Each subitem As JObject In item.Values
                                    strfamily = subitem("family")
                                Next

                        End Select

                    Next
                Next
```

I was hoping that it gets me Given and family but when debugging it shows me this error : 
{"Can not cast an object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'."}

Comment: What's the reason for these lines: `Dim result2 As String = Replace(director.ToString, "{[", "")
                    result2 = Replace(result2.ToString, "]}", "")` ? You shouldn't be manipulating the JSON like a string. Parse it to an object and then process it. No need for string nonsense.

Comment: Anyway, which line exactly is giving the error? It would help to know that.

Comment: this is the line with the foreach in the CASE "GIVEN"

Comment: Well, since the value in "given" is "Ju", this is a string, and not an object. Therefore it cannot turn it into a JObject, which is supposed to represent a JSON object. That's what the error is telling you. Your `as JObject` is trying to force it to be a JObject, but that's impossible because the value is only a simple string. JSON.NET uses the `JValue` class to represent those - again if you look, the error message is telling you what class you should have used, because it's telling you that the variable you're trying to force into a JObject is actually a JValue..

Comment: you were right about jvalue but when I want to parse value this one shows me a error message :       {"Error parsing NaN value. Path '', line 1, position 2."}

Comment: again, which line is throwing that error?

Comment: the same line into  foreach i used  JValue.Parse(subitem)

Comment: show me how the whole line looks now. Not sure why you need to use .Parse()?

Comment: For Each subitem As JValue In item.Values
                                        strgiven = JToken.Parse(subitem)

                Next

Comment: You can just use `subItem.Value` if you want the value. Not sure why you want to parse it to a JToken?

Comment: No, you don't. `strgiven = subItem.Value As String` ought to do the trick. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Value.htm

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, I haven't used this for a while. But that's what it looks like you should be able to do

Comment: the jtoken was a mistake   , 
Thank you a lot that works well

Comment: to access the data of the table NAME  you would recommend me what?
knowing that there are objects in an object encompassing everything.

Comment: you'd have to parse the name object as a JObject as far as I know. You have to know what the JSON is going to contain before you parse it. Or you have to do a test to find out, if the structure is uncertain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
For Each subitem As JValue In item.Values
  strgiven = subitem.Value As String
Next
```

The reason for this is that since the value in "given" is "Ju", this is a string, and not an object. Therefore it cannot turn it into a JObject, which is supposed to represent a JSON object. That's what the error is telling you. Your as JObject is trying to force it to be a JObject, but that's impossible because the value is only a simple string. JSON.NET uses the JValue class to represent those - again if you look, the error message is telling you what class you should have used, because it's telling you that the variable you're trying to force into a JObject is actually a JValue. And once you've got a JValue, you can simply access its "Value" property and convert it to the type you want (string, in this case)